# can't use scrapy althought all instalation stages done properly

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, pip, pyopenssl

I have a project related to NLP course, which is about to classify colloquial dialects in Arabic. I need to scrap a lot of data from different domains to tbe train properly.
I'm using `Python 2.7` on Windows 10 64-bit with Eclipse IDE (using PyDev32), the top popular and effective framework I have found is `Scrapy`

> I have followed all installation steps **carefully**:
>
> when installing with `pip install scrapy`, it outputs NO error
>
> BUT when I start a project or executing `scrapy shell "google.com"`, I got the error (the last four lines):

```
from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

**another error:**

```
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
```

**Notes:**

- I'm using Python of 32-bit because I noticed (after googling) Scrapy doesn't work on 64-bit
- I have found many solutions on Stack Overflow but all in vain, thus I don't my question is duplicate
- I tried to turn ON/OFF the firewall with no benefit
- I installed both versions of OpenSSL (32bit/64bit) and nothing fixed
- I thought that the problem is with `lxml` but it's NOT related to it.
- I'm totally beginner, and my project should be finished in less than a week
- I test running `scrapy` on Anaconda (as they recommended), I got the same errors

I'm so sorry for my modest question, I'm so optimistic to got anyone's help :)

Comment: I also had problems with installing scrapy on Windows. I solved it by using the the wheel from [Unofficial Windows Binary Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). I don't know if it's related to this specific error but if you want to give it a try I recommend installing the lxml wheel first and then scrapy.

Comment: unfortunately, It doesn't fix my problem

Comment: After many attempts to install (offline by unofficial site), I got the same error
"Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?"

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely having trouble with `lxml` dependancy which is notoriously difficult to compile on windows systems.
The best thing you can do is install a binary of it as [mentioned in the official docummentation](http://lxml.de/installation.html#installation)
You can download unofficial binaries directly [from here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)

Comment: I tried all packages of what you metioned about ... still not fix my problem

Comment: why don't we suppose that the problem in with OpenSSL, although I installed the completed binary setup (Win32OpenSSL-1_1_0c.exe)

Comment: Another suggestion, mr.@Granitosaurus >> do u know any other tool that can scrap web elements and export it to python